# Indesign SDK - Document based Persistent

Tags: visual-c++, plugins, sdk, adobe-indesign

I am new for "indesign SDK" Plugin development. Is there any example for document based persistent?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for their developer pre-release. There you will find some SDK samples which can help you with this.
These SDKs should also be a part of CC https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/indesign.html